# Gul'dan's role in opening the portal

Tags: warcraft, warcraft-2016

In WarCraft, it is said that Medivh is responsible for the opening of portal to the orchish homeworld- Outland.So what role did Gul'dan play? We saw Gul'dan drawing energy from the prisoners, what is it used for, if Medivh is actually opening the portal?

Comment: No, Gul'dan used fel magic to drain the life out of captive Draenei in order to sustain the portal.  But he needed someone from other side to help him open portal. Thats where Medivh infected by fel magic comes in.

Comment: On the other side? But at the climax, both the Gul'dan and Medivh were on the same side.I mean Azeroth.

Comment: Again the same thing. Medivh helps to open portal, Gul'dan uses fel magic to sustain portal